# scrollTop not returning the distance above the viewport

Tags: jquery

Does anyone see why scrollTop() doesn't return the amount of #box above the viewport when it is scrolled up in this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qD7Yh/ -? Clicking the box returns the current scrollTop.

The jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#box').click(function() {
    alert("scrollTop() for box is " + $('#box').scrollTop());
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Your element doesn't have scrollBar.

Comment: So if I scroll at the right so part of the box is out of view, how can I tell how much of it is missing above the viewport?  I thought that's what scrollTop(0 did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `scrollTop()` returns the distance from the top of the element you're calling, so in the current syntax, the function returns the amount scrolled *inside* the box, which, since it doesn't have any scrollbar or scrollable content, is 0. Your code to work, you should have some overflowing content in your `<div>`, which should allow it to scroll and thus increment the `scrollTop()` value

Try this:

css:

```
#box{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    line-height:200px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: beige;
    border:1px solid brown;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="box"><p>Hello there</p><p>This is a test</p></div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#box').click(function() {
        alert("scrollTop() for box is " + $('#box').scrollTop());
    });
});
```

### Finding out the document/window scrollTop()

If you'd like to find out how much of the document has been scrolled (since the box is bigger than the window's height), use `$(window).scrollTop()` or `$(document).scrollTop()`

Comment: Actually to do what I want to do, find how much of #box is above the viewport, I need do the scrollTop() on window:  alert("scrollTop() for box is " + $(window).scrollTop()); - Thanks

Comment: oh, so the first solution was right? Yeah, then you're better off with `$(document).scrollTop()` or `$(window).scrollTop()`

Comment: Yes.  I didn't see your comment when I made my comment above.